# Ruby: Continue adding each value in an array until it reaches the max set value

Tags: ruby

I can't think of a way on how to sum up the values inside the given array and stops when it reaches the max value. Like the example on below, it should add only 60 and 80. The array could be more than 3 values.

```
def sum (array, max_value)
  #code here
end

puts sum([60, 80, 90], 200)
```

Comment: gut feeling is to use `inject`.

Comment: I've tried using inject. However, I can't think of a way on how to do it to stop the loop when it exceeds the max value.

Comment: I think you can use an `if-expression` with `break`, passing `break` the desired value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always just cap it with `inject`:

```
def sum(array, max_value)
  array.inject do |s, v|
    s + v <= max_value ? s + v : s
  end
end
```

Since you have control over what value is chained forward, you can stop adding to the sum if it'd exceed your threshold.

**Edit**: If you're looking for this to break out on longer lists:

```
def sum (array, max_value)
  array.inject do |s, v|
    break s if s + v > max_value

    s + v
  end
end
```

Comment: `inject` supports `break value` to avoid tail iteration on huge arrays.

Comment: ...or return from the method when `s + v > max_value`.

Comment: That's a good point. This was just a quick and dirty solution, so I've added a second more efficient version incorporating that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I prefer to avoid `return` wherever possible to avoid unexpected failures whne moving this code to lambdas.

Comment: Yeah, `return` inside a block can be trouble, so `break` here is a better call. It also doesn't make any assumptions about the surrounding code.

Comment: Using an instance of `Enumerator` is an option to avoid all the `break`s and `if`s. Does require a few more lines of code though.

Answer (score 2):

```
add = ->(arr, max, current = 0) do
  val = arr.shift
  arr.empty? || val + current > max ? \
    current : add(arr, max, val + current)
end
add.([60, 80, 90], 200)
#⇒ 140
```

The prevent a mutation of the original array, when passed by reference, one should `dup` it in advance:

```
arr, max = [60, 80, 90], 200
add.(arr.dup, max)
```

FWIW: the solution that does not mutate an input:

```
add = lambda do |arr, max, current = 0, entry = true|
  arr = arr.dup if entry
  val = arr.shift
  arr.empty? || val + current > max ? \
    current : add(arr, max, val + current, false)
end
```

Comment: Is the \ strictly necessary there? This also consumes the input array which may be undesirable, but it's an interesting solution.

Comment: @tadman no, but I do put it everywhere the line is unexpectedly breaking. Regarding consuming the input, please check the part II of this answer.

Comment: Ah, the sneaky fine print at the end. Usually it's the responsibility of the function to not mangle things, not the caller to send in a disposable argument.

Comment: @tadman in this particular case (as in every case when recursion is on the scene) it’s unfortunately impossible without introducing the forth dumb boolean argument to denote whether it’s the first iteration to `dup` an input.

Answer (score -1):

Ruby is not my first language, but you could do a simple loop:

```
def msum(arr,m)
    i=0
    sum=0
    arr.each do |e| 
        sum+=e
        break if sum>m
        i+=1
    end
    return arr.take(i)
end
```